# Why is the top level package being removed? Python

Tags: python, import, package

I created a`Python` package for one of the projects I'm currently working on. The top package is called `integration`, and inside there's another called `testcases` and the name of the test. I installed the modules via `pip`: produced a `pip wheels` dist, and installed. Also, there's a top level script called `integration` that's copied to the command line.
The directory structure looks like:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    integration/
         README.md
         __init__.py
         integration # script
         testcases/
              __init__.py
              foo_test.py
              bar_test.py
```

So, from the command line, after a `pip install`, I run:

```
integration --wait-time 1
```

Everything goes smooth till it starts to import the packages:

```
*** Update *****
# os.getcwd() : /home/ubuntu/project
*****
2016-02-17 17:03:25 - project - INFO - Module: integration.testcases.bar_test
2016-02-17 17:03:25 - project - INFO - class_str: BarTest
2016-02-17 17:03:25 - project - INFO - class_data: [u'bar_test', u'py']
2016-02-17 17:03:25 - project - ERROR - Failed to instantiate class integration.testcases.bar_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/integration", line 131, in load_class
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named testcases.bar_test
2016-02-17 17:03:25 - project - ERROR - No module named testcases.bar_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/integration", line 131, in load_class
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
```

Sure I didn't try to load `testcases.bar_test`: I passed `integration.testcases.bar_test`. Doing the same thing in the terminal I'm successful:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-3-6-9:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import importlib
>>> module = importlib.import_module('integration.testcases.bar_test')
2016-02-17 17:10:00 - easyprocess - DEBUG - version=0.2.2
2016-02-17 17:10:00 - pyvirtualdisplay - DEBUG - version=0.1.5
```

Here's the source code for the method that imports those classes:

```
try:
   # filename -> bar_test.py
   # class_str -> BarTest
   class_data = filename.split(".")
   current_path = "{0}.{1}".format("integration.testcases", class_data[0])
   module_path = self.format_path(current_path)
   self.log.info("Module: %s" % module_path)
   module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
   return getattr(module, class_str)
except Exception, e:
   self.log.exception("Failed to instantiate class %s" % module_path)
   self.log.exception(e)
```

`format_path(path)` only replaces `'/'` by `'.'`, nothing else, so

```
foo/bar/bat -> foo.bar.bat
```

I wonder why `importlib` is using `testcases.bar_test` instead of `integration.testcases.bar_test`. Any clues?

Comment: What's the working directory? Could you add `import os; print os.getcwd()` as the first line of `try` block and tell us the output?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo will do it.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I've updated with the os.getcwd() ... it's in `/home/ubuntu/project1`

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo but anyways, the full path of the package is given: `integration.testcases.foo_test` ... as you can see I load it from the command line just fine. I wonder why it's being chopped off to `testcases.foo_test`.

Comment: I thought that maybe you're in integration folder already... But it's not the case.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I'm running that from `/home/ubuntu`. There are some `os.chdir()` behind the scenes, but I don't think that's a factor (or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are running this from `/home/ubuntu` does matter. The way Python iterpreter search for modules is described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Investigate where does it look for them in your case with:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If `/home/ubuntu/project1` is not there then `import integration.whatever` will fail.

Then you have 3 options:
- put your entry script in `/home/ubuntu/project1` folder
- add `/home/ubuntu/project1` to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
- add `/home/ubuntu/project1` to `sys.path`  within your entry script

Comment: ElmoVanKielmo, I actually have them ... I just didn't list. I updated the question with that info.